# CSS - width not honored on span tag

Tags: css, css-float, html

I have a issue with one of my spans.  Please consider the following styles:

```
.form_container .col1che
{
float: left; 
width: 4%; 
text-align: left;    
}

.form_container .col2che
{
float: left; 
width: 80%; 
text-align:left;
}

.form_container .col3che
{
float: right; 
width: 13%; 
text-align:right;
}
```

These 3 spans in my code:

```
<div class="row"><!-- start: "row" -->
     <span class="col1che">        
          <?php  //some db feeds    ?>        
     </span>
     <span class="col2che">
          <?php  //some db feeds    ?>
     </span>
     <span class="col3che">
          <?php  //some db feeds    ?>
     </span>
     <div class="clear"></div>
</div><!-- end: "row" -->
```

The problem occurs when there is no data to be displayed in "COL1CHE" (or maybe even in any of them although I'm not sure) when there is no data this span "collapses" and its width is not honored.  This happens in Firefox, in IE it doesn't "collapse".

I included a "clear" class to see if this helps but to no avail.

Any ideas?

Comment: hmmm, what you guys say makes perfect sense, but for some reason even after adding display:block it still "collapses"

funny, if i add a border to the column class it will show the proper width even if there is no content. but if there is no content, no border, it just collapses

Comment: o yea, another thing, how come if my spans were not set up as blocks and if there is content within them, then the widths are set up correctly like in the style sheet? (not that im debating whether widths are honored for inline elements, im just curious why they worked for me)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`display: block` **will not** help you here because when float is activated, the elements is automatically switched to block mode, whatever its initial mode, so your width should work.

The problem may be with the empty `<span>` tag which might not be rendered because of some obscure rule I cannot remember. You should try preventing your span from being empty, maybe by adding a `&nbsp;` if the content is empty.

Comment: ok great, floated elements becoming automatically blocks explains alot in terms of the behaviour i saw on my page...

i tried the nbsp tip and it worked great thanks...if someone who knows why no content would make this collapse maybe they can chime in just to clarify this curious behaviour, but for now this is a great fix.

Answer (score 68):

Span is an inline element and you can therefore not set a width. To set a width you must first set it to a block element with

```
display:block;
```

After that you can set a width. Since span is a native inline element, you can use inline-block too and it will even work in IE:

```
display:inline-block;
```

Answer (score 32):

Width is not honored because span is an inline element.  To fix this, add:

```
display: inline-block;
```

Depending on your situation, `display: inline-block` may be better than `display: block` because any content after the span won't be forced onto a new line.

Answer (score 3):

To make this work simply add

```
display: block;
```

To the style.

Answer (score 2):

Display `block` and optionally float `left` helped me.

```
display: block;
float: left;
```