# Why are some of my links not clickable but some are?

Tags: html, css

In the following code for a calendar, links if there is an event and also links for today are not clickable.

Note that I have substituted `www.google.com` for the hyperlink. In the actual app it points to the daily view of calendar.

Would be extremely grateful if someone could spot the error. Thank you.

Links for 2, 3, 4 and 7 work but links for 5, 6 and 8 do not work.

The [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6YRRF/1/).

```css
div.event {
  position: relative;
  vertical-aligh: top;
  z-index: 3;
  top: 25px;
  text-width: 70px;
}

a.event {
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: top;
  z-index: 3;
  //    top:-15px;
  text-width: 70px;
}

a.day-number {
  vertical-align: top;
  background: #999;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 0px;
  padding: 4px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  float: right;
}

a.theday-number {
  vertical-align: top;
  background: #999;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 0px;
  padding: 4px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  float: right;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="calendar-row">
    <td class="calendar-day"><span style="position:relative;height:400px;width:70px;"><a href="http://www.google.com" class="day-number">2</a><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p></span></td>
    <td class="calendar-day"><span style="position:relative;height:400px;width:70px;"><a href="http://www.google.com" class="day-number">3</a><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p></span></td>
    <td class="calendar-day"><span style="position:relative;height:400px;width:70px;"><a href="http://www.google.com" class="day-number">4</a><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p></span></td>
    <td class="calendar-day"><span style="position:relative;height:400px;width:70px;"><a href="http://www.google.com" class="day-number">5</a><div class="event">6:00 PM<br><a href="eventdetail.php?id=1438">drinks</a></div></span></td>
    <td class="calendar-day"><span style="position:relative;height:400px;width:70px;"><a href="http://www.google.com" class="theday-number">6</a><div class="event"><a href="eventdetail.php?id=1441">Test</a></div></span></td>
    <td class="calendar-day"><span style="position:relative;height:400px;width:70px;"><a href="http://www.google.com" class="day-number">7</a><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p></span></td>
    <td class="calendar-day"><span style="position:relative;height:400px;width:70px;"><a href="http://www.google.com" class="day-number">8</a><div class="event">6:00 PM<br><a href="eventdetail.php?id=1419">party</a></div></span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Ffiddle.jshell.net%2F6YRRF%2F1%2Fshow%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Comment: For some reason it appears that they become clickable if you remove the `position: relative;` from the inline style

Comment: Remove the DIV inside the SPAN tag, the number 5 is now clickable.

Comment: also you have some errors in the css code

Comment: a div within a span is creating a problem..

Comment: xec, for some reason SO will not let me upvote your comment but removing the position: relative fixed it.

Answer (score 6):

You need to move the `<p>` and `<div>` tags out of the `<span>`

`<p>` and `<div>` are block-level elements and a `<span>` is an inline element, and you can't have a block element inside an inline element.

Answer (score 5):

When using `position:absolute;`and links together, there are issues with z-index. In order for the link to work, add a high z-index value,
For example,

```
z-index:9999999;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of div within a span use other html element. It seems this is the problem. If you remove those divs, elements are clickable..

Answer (score 0):

Add a display block to your span inside your td calendar-day and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, you have some elements overlapping one another. Part of the problem is that you are setting width on an inline element (span).

Discussed here on stackOverflow:

[CSS - width not honored on span tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1161477/css-width-not-honored-on-span-tag)

I added the display: inline-block property to your span tags and also added some background color just for contrast here:

```
<span style="display: inline-block;position:relative;height:400px;width:70px;">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6YRRF/16/

All your links seem to be working now.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I see the links are clickable if you remove the `<span></span>` tag which you have placed inside `<td></td>`. I suggest you add styling inside `<td>` instead of using `<span>`.

Try. It might work :)

Answer (score 0):

You can either remove `<p>` tag or provide css(display: inline-block) to `<p>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

For those who didn't address their problem out of the answers provided here, check html element or it's parent element to don't have this CSS property:

```
pointer-events: none;
```

Answer (score -1):

Please remove the span wrap inside td. And Yes! correct your css.

```
<style>
    div.event {
    position:relative; 
    vertical-align:top;
    z-index:3; 
    top:25px;
    width: 70px;
}
a.event {
    position:relative; 
    vertical-align:top;
    z-index:3; 
//  top:-15px;
    width: 70px;
}
a.day-number  {
    vertical-align:top; 
    background:#999; 
    z-index:2; 
    top:0px;    
    padding:4px; 
    color:#fff; 
    font-weight:bold; 
    width:18px; 
    text-align:center;
    float:right;
}
a.theday-number  {
    vertical-align:top; 
    background:#999; 
    z-index:2; 
    top:0px;    
    padding:4px; 
    color:#fff; 
    font-weight:bold; 
    width:18px; 
    text-align:center;
    float:right;
    background-color:red; 
}

</style>
```